# Linq like function GroupMultipleValBy

Tags: linq, f#

In the process of learning the awesomness that is F# + Linq I came to a problem I can not solve(nicely) using functional, OOP, nor Linq like syntax, would anyone be willing to help?

Lets say my input is the following sequence:

```fs
let db = seq [ ("bob", 90, ['x';'y'])
               ("bob", 70, ['z'])
               ("frank", 20, ['b'])
               ("charlie", 10, ['c']) ]
```

Rows could read for example "Student bob has enrolled in x,y in semester 90"

What I need is this instead:

```fs
[ ("bob",  [90; 70],  ['x'; 'y'; 'z']) 
  ("frank",    [20],  ['b'])
  ("charlie",  [10],  ['c']) ]
```

This would read instead "Bob has finished semesters 90,70 and taken x,y,z".

Linq/Relational approach usualy gives the most readable solutions to such problems. But the best I can come up with is:

```fs
type Student = string
type Semester = int
type Class = char

let restructure (inp:seq<Student * Semester * Class list>) = query {
        for (student, semester, classes) in inp do
        groupValBy (semester,classes) student into data 
        yield (data.Key, Seq.map fst data, Seq.collect snd data)
    }
```

Which is neither readable, nor fast, nor pretty, nor idiomatic, and due to intricacies of F# requires that I write the input type signature...

Is there a better way some GroupMultipleValBy function?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not insist on using the `query` syntax (which is needed if you are working with databases, but is just one of the options when working with in-memory data), then I would probably use simple `Seq.groupBy` function:

```
db 
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (name, _, _) -> name)
|> Seq.map (fun (name, group) ->
    name,
    group |> Seq.map (fun (_, sem, _) -> sem),
    group |> Seq.collect (fun (_, _, courses) -> courses) )
```

Here, we are saying that we want to group records by student name and return a triple with:

- The student name, which was used as the grouping key
- Get semester of all the records
- Collect all the courses they attended

This is not shorter than your version, but I think a combination of `groupBy` and `map` is a fairly common pattern that is quite easy to understand. That said, I'm quite curious to see other answers! I can imagine there would be a nicer way of doing this...

Comment: Using named parameters is a lot clearer. But as I used queries elsewhere I will keep looking. I believe queries usually provide a solution in such primitive terms, that even non-fsharpers understand it. Which is a big plus.

Comment: Did I perhaps select the answer prematurely?

Comment: @arctiq I believe you can change the selected answer - and absolutely feel free to do that if you find other answers more useful!

Answer (score 4):

If you can stick to "classic" F# code you can rewrite it in a more readable way (especially by using locals to make the code even more readable)
*Well it seems [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825001/4925216) beat me to this, we've gone roughly the same road with some "quirks" in the middle*

```
let restructure inp =
  // could have been defined at a more global scope as helpers
  let fst3 (x, _, _) = x
  let flip f y x = f x y

  let folder cont (student, semester, classes) (_, semesters, allClasses) =
    cont (student, semester :: semesters, classes @ allClasses)

  let initialState = "", [], []

  inp
  |> Seq.groupBy fst3
  |> Seq.map (snd >> flip (Seq.fold folder id) initialState)
```

The hard part to understand is the `folder` one, to keep semesters in the wanted order we either have to add an extra step reversing that part or as done here using a continuation

That (and the use of `flip` to keep it point free) added with the use of `@` makes me think Tomas code is "better" (but his answer makes semesters and classes `seq` instead of `list`)

---

*Addendum*

Here's Tomas code written in a way I find more readable (but that's a matter of taste) and maybe more agnostic about what's being manipulated although it's longer
*[that doesn't take anything to it's answer which is great]*

```
let restructure inp =
  // could have been defined at a more global scope as helpers
  let fst3 (x, _, _) = x
  let snd3 (_, y, _) = y
  let trd3 (_, _, z) = z

  let mapping (key, values) =
    key,
    // replace with commented part to have lists instead of seqs
    values |> Seq.map snd3, //[ for value in values -> snd3 value ],
    values |> Seq.collect trd3 //[ for value in values do yield! trd3 value ]

  inp
  |> Seq.groupBy fst3
  |> Seq.map mapping
```

Comment: Your modified Petriceks  solution is more readable, I don't know whether it's enough to pick it as the correct answer. While the first code snippet seems needlessly abstract and complex.

Comment: While you can define helpers for `fst3`, `snd3` and `trd3` to avoid explicit functions, I think that loses some of the meaning that the original code had when you had to name things (`semester` and `courses`) and so you could read it and get some idea about the things that you're working with...

Comment: In reality, I would probably avoid three-element tuples and use a record instead. Then you would use record properties which would require you to be clear about what you're working with - I like the idea of using list comprehensions - then you'd end up with: `[ for v in group -> v.Semester]` and `[for v in group do yield! v.Courses ]`